# cpp:template - Как решить проблему " cannot convert from 'char* const' to int "?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Разбираюсь с template-ми на c++. Написал небольшую функцию которая принимает, какой-то объект MyJSON* _value и в реализации сделал разбор в зависимости от типа содержимого что бы функция возращала его результат. Компилятор выдает ошибку   **Error  224 error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char *const ' to 'int' *_myjson.h**

код template:

```
template<typename T> 
T get_value_from_json(const MyJSON* _value)
{
    if (_value->type == 1)
        return _value->valueint;

    if (_value->type == 2)    
        return _value->valuedouble;

    if (_value->type == 3) {   
        return _value->valuestring;
}

// ------------------------------------------------

// примерно что хотелось бы увидеть:
int a = get_value_from_json(json_value);

// если значения нет, то возврат значения nullptr
const char* str = get_value_from_json(json_value);
```

Может есть возможность через специализацию шаблона, указать какой именно тип следует обрабатывать компилятору с учетом LVALUE? Или как пример есть static_assert, может что то подобное можно реализовать для выбора какое условие для конкретного типа обрабатывать?

к сожалению не совсем разобрался как решать подобные вещи с помощью template-ов.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я не уверен, что темплейты Вам помогут сделать то ,что Вы сейчас пишете. Вы пытаетесь из одной функции вернуть результаты разных типов. Тип возвращаемого значения должен быть тот, которым специфицирован шаблон, тот тип, который будет подставлен вместо Т

Comment: хорошо, а можно как то указать в зависимости от _value->type, что указанный тип Т будет int или const char* в зависимости от условия (на уровне реализации тела функции)? или подобные функции надо разбивать на две функции в зависимости от ожидаемого результата? Я так понял что если тип был бы double или int то компилятор собрал указанный текст..., а как быть есть ли тип const char* ?

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, то никак. Вы в самом темплейте пишете три return с разными типами. Это некорректно. Вариант решения Вам уже предложил Chorkov

Comment: Цель - которую хочу добиться, что бы внутренняя реализация template, могла через условия возращать и обрабатывать тот блок реализации внутри, исходя из типа LVALUE. Не знаю может есть какая то возможность реализовать это грамотно через std::is_integral<T> или что-то-то наподобие static_assert....

Comment: Мне кажется, такое возможно на этапе компиляции, когда Вы инстанцируете шаблон определенным типом. Но не на этапе выполнения.

Comment: Если компилятору указать спецификацию template, как пример: auto a = get_value_from_json<int>(json_value); он логично выдаст ошибку с которой я обратился, но я пытаюсь изучить каким образом можно в зависимости от LVALUE сделать возможность выбора, на этапе компиляции, какой блок обрабатывать (компилировать) для данного вызова, какой нет..., хотя могу рассуждать не коректно, пока не хватает знаний в этой области...

Answer (score 2):

Шаблоны здесь не нужны.

Функция может возвращать только значение конкретного типа. Можно эмулировать динамическую типизацию с помощью std::variant или std::any, но это не очень удобно.

Больше подойдет proxy-объект с несколькими операторами приведения типа. Примерно так:

```
class json_value_proxy
{
    const MyJSON* _value;
public:
    json_value_proxy(const MyJSON* value) : _value(value) {}

    operator int () const {
        if(_value==nullptr) 
            throw std::runtime_error("No value!");
        if (_value->type == 1) 
            return  _value->valueint;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong type!");
    }
    operator double () const  { ... }
    operator const char* () const { ... }
};
json_value_proxy get_value_from_json(const MyJSON* _value) {
      return json_value_proxy(_value);
}
```

Следует отдельно обдумать политику поведения при несоответствии запрошенного типа и типа переданного в _value. Приведение типа, lexcal_cast или исключение? Эта политика совсем не очевидна из постановки задачи.

Comment: стараюсь разобраться, как можно все таки сделать через проверку типов на этапе компиляции, что бы компилятор понимал, какой if использовать в зависимости от LVALUE. За Ваш пример спасибо - отличный паттерн!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, как вы написали, только вызывать надо соответствующим образом:

```
auto a = get_value_from_json<int>(json_value);
```

и так далее, меняя тип.

Comment: Это не скомпилируется. Как минимум, в функции будут нужны if constexpr, но судя по коду, их там быть не может.

Comment: @Qwertiy если все ретурны приводимы к типу `T`, то всё должно скомпилироваться

Comment: Судя по вопросу там int, double и char*. Первые два - ладно, последний что-то я не уверен, что удастся без танцев с бубном привести к double.

Comment: есть вызывать примерно как Вы написали auto a = get_value_from_json<int>(json_value);, то на строчке  return _value->valuestring; компилятор будет ругаться что не может преобразовать const char* в int ... эх пробовал так в самом начале :-)